# Android jetpack compose fragment without xml

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Goodnight! I'm using drawerContent and navigationIcon to create the menu, but can I create a Fragment () without xml? in compose jetpack. If anyone has any references I would be grateful ...

Comment: Why are you trying to use a Fragment in Compose?

Comment: I want to do something similar to do a menu navigation

Comment: @RafaelSouza https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Compose you can try something different.
You can navigate between composables using the [Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nested-nav) (currently in `1.0.0-alpha10`)

Create a `NavController` with:

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
```

and define a `NavHost` with the destinations:

```
NavHost(
    navController,
    startDestination = "entry1"
) {
    composable("entry1") { Entry1(..) }
    composable("entry2") { Entry2(..) }
    composable("entry3") { Entry3(..) }
}
```

To simplify the navigation just create a sealed class (it is not mandatory).

```
sealed class Screen(val route: String, @StringRes val resourceId: Int) {
    object Entry1 : Screen("entry1", R.string.entry1)
    object Entry2 : Screen("entry2", R.string.entry2)
    object Entry3 : Screen("entry3", R.string.entry3)
}
```

and change the `NavHost` to:

```
NavHost(
    navController,
    startDestination = Screen.Entry1.route
) {
    composable(Screen.Entry1.route) { Entry1(/*..*/) }
    composable(Screen.Entry2.route) { Entry2(/*..*/) }
    composable(Screen.Entry3.route) { Entry3(/*..*/) }
}
```

Now just use a **`Scaffold`** to create a drawerContent and navigationIcon to open the menu and navigate to the destination:

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
val current by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

val items = listOf(
    Screen.Entry1,
    Screen.Entry2,
    Screen.Entry3
)

Scaffold(
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    drawerContent = {
        //val currentRoute = current?.arguments?.getString(KEY_ROUTE)
        val currentRoute = current?.destination?.route

        items.forEach { screen ->
            val selected = currentRoute == screen.route
            val selectedColor = if (selected) Color.Yellow else Color.Transparent
            Row(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(32.dp)
                .background(selectedColor)
                .clickable {
                    scope.launch { scaffoldState.drawerState.close()}
                    navController.navigate(screen.route) {
                        popUpTo = navController.graph.startDestination
                        launchSingleTop = true
                    }
                }) {
                   Text(stringResource(screen.resourceId))
            }
        }
    },
    topBar = {
        TopAppBar(){
            IconButton(
                onClick = {
                    scope.launch { scaffoldState.drawerState.open() }
                }
            ) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.Menu,"")
            }
        }
    },
    content = {
        NavHost(
            navController,
            startDestination = Screen.Entry1.route
        ) {
          composable(Screen.Entry1.route) { Entry1(/*..*/) }
          composable(Screen.Entry2.route) { Entry2(/*..*/) }
          composable(Screen.Entry3.route) { Entry3(/*..*/) }
        }
    }
)
```

where:

```
@Composable
fun Entry1(navigateTo: () -> Unit) {

    Column(){
         /*.....*/
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: When I add the implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha10" to the gradle, it gives an error in my application

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.quitanda, PID: 18006
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field Companion of type Landroidx/compose/foundation/layout/BoxScope$Companion; in class Landroidx/compose/foundation/layout/BoxScope; or its superclasses (declaration of 'androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxScope' appears in /data/app/com.example.quitanda-sLmYSWEY6MCvkQJc8-SiSw==/base.apk)

Comment: @RafaelSouza Are you using compose 1.0.0-beta04?

Comment: No, I am using compose 1.0.0-alpha10, other modifications I made was to add an impement to image:  implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-coil:0.7.0"

Comment: I'm emulating on my phone J Prime 5

Comment: @RafaelSouza You have to use 1.0.0-beta04 and navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha10

Comment: how do I set compose 1.0.0-beta04 ?

Comment: @RafaelSouza just update the compose dependencies to 1.0.0-beta04

Comment: inside the dependencies { have $ compose_version I change that

Answer (score -1):

It worked my class looked like this:

```
package com.example.quitanda

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.CircleShape
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Add
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Menu
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberCoroutineScope
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.testTag
import androidx.compose.ui.res.colorResource
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.compose.*
import com.google.accompanist.coil.CoilImage
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val responseState = mutableStateOf("")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent{
            MainContent()
        }
    }


    @Composable
    private fun RecyclerView(){
        Text(text = responseState.value)

        LazyColumn(/*contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp),*/
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
            for(i in 0..50){
                item {
                    Text(text = "Categoria 2, categoria 1",fontSize = 15.sp,
                            color=Color.White,modifier= Modifier
                        .background(
                                colorResource(id = R.color.red)
                        )
                        .fillMaxWidth(100f))
                    Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                            modifier= Modifier
                                .padding(bottom = 8.dp)
                                .fillMaxWidth(100f)
                        ) {

                        Images("https://quitandadivino.com.br/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.quitandadivino.com.br%2Fuploads%2Fabacaxi_perola_20afb6c700.jpg&w=300&q=75")

                        Column {
                            Text("Abacaxi",fontSize = 20.sp)
                            Text("Aprox. 0,185g/un",fontSize = 15.sp,color=Color.LightGray)
                            Text("R$ 120,00/UN",fontSize = 15.sp,color=Color.Red)
                            Text("R$ 120,00/KG",fontSize = 15.sp,color=Color.Red)
                        }

                        Column(modifier= Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth(100f)
                            .padding(5.dp)
                           ,horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End) {
                            Button(
                                    onClick = {},
                                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                                            backgroundColor = Color.Red,
                                            contentColor = Color.White)
                            ) {
                                Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.comprar))
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Text(text = " ",fontSize = 15.sp,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(bottom = 2.dp) // margin
                                .fillMaxWidth(100f)
                                .background(colorResource(id = R.color.red))
                        )

                }
            }
        }

    }

    private fun onPressView(){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Testar",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Composable
    private fun Images(url:String){
        Card(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(110.dp)
                    .testTag("circle")
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .clickable(onClick = { onPressView() })
                    .padding(10.dp),
                shape = CircleShape,
                elevation = 2.dp,
        ) {

            CoilImage(
                    data = url,
                    contentDescription = "Abacaxi",
                    fadeIn = true
            )
        }
    }

    @Composable
    private fun MainContent(){
        val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        val navController = rememberNavController()

         Scaffold(
                topBar = {
                    TopBar(scope,scaffoldState)
                         },
                content={

                    NavHost(
                            navController,
                            startDestination = Screen.Entry1.route
                    ) {
                        composable(Screen.Entry1.route) { Entry1() }
                        composable(Screen.Entry2.route) { Entry2() }
                        composable(Screen.Entry3.route) { Entry3() }
                    }
                },
                floatingActionButton = { MainFab() },
                drawerContent = {
                    DrawerContent(scope,scaffoldState,navController)
                },
                scaffoldState = scaffoldState
        )
    }


    @Composable
    private fun DrawerContent(scope: CoroutineScope,scaffoldState:ScaffoldState
    ,navController: NavController
    ){

        val items = listOf(
                Screen.Entry1,
                Screen.Entry2,
                Screen.Entry3
        )

        Text("Drawer content", style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5)

        items.forEach { screen ->
            Row(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(32.dp)
                .clickable {
                    scope.launch { scaffoldState.drawerState.close() }
                    navController.navigate(screen.route) {
                        popUpTo = navController.graph.startDestination
                        launchSingleTop = true
                    }
                }) {
                Text(stringResource(screen.resourceId))
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    private fun TopBar(scope: CoroutineScope,scaffoldState:ScaffoldState){
        TopAppBar(title={
            Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_name))
        },
                backgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.green),
                contentColor = Color.White,
                navigationIcon ={
                    IconButton(
                            onClick = {scope.launch { scaffoldState.drawerState.open() } }
                    ) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Menu, contentDescription ="Menu" )
                    }
                }
        )
    }

    @Composable
    private fun MainFab () {
        FloatingActionButton(onClick = {showAddForm()}) {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Add, contentDescription = "Adicionar")
        }
    }

   private var resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // There are no request codes
            val response = result.data?.getParcelableExtra<AddUserState>("user_state")
            responseState.value = response.toString()
        }
    }

    private fun showAddForm() {
        val intent = Intent(this, FormActivity::class.java)
        resultLauncher.launch(intent)
    }

    @Composable
    private fun Entry1(){
        Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.entry1))
        RecyclerView()
    }

    @Composable
    private fun Entry2(){
        Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.entry2))
    }

    @Composable
    private fun Entry3(){
        Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.entry3))
    }
}
```

@Gabriele Mariotti Thank you very much