# How to add FloatingActionButton in ModelDrawer Layout in Jetpack compose in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I want to create Drawer Layout with Floating action button using Navigation Component in Jetpack Compose.
I am trying with below code But not able to add Floating action button. I want to add FAB button bottom right of the screen.

```
    Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
    val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Closed)
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val openDrawer = {
        scope.launch {
            drawerState.open()
        }
    }
    ModalDrawer(
        drawerState = drawerState,
        gesturesEnabled = drawerState.isOpen,
        drawerContent = {
            Drawer(
                onDestinationClicked = { route ->
                    scope.launch {
                        drawerState.close()
                    }
                    navController.navigate(route) {
                        popUpTo = navController.graph.startDestination
                        launchSingleTop = true
                    }
                }
            )
        },
    ) {
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = DrawerScreens.Home.route
        ) {
            composable(DrawerScreens.Home.route) {
                Home(
                    openDrawer = {
                        openDrawer()
                    }
                )
            }
            composable(DrawerScreens.Account.route) {
                Account(
                    openDrawer = {
                        openDrawer()
                    }
                )
            }
            composable(DrawerScreens.Settings.route) {
                Settings(
                    openDrawer = {
                        openDrawer()
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Scaffold`.
If the `drawerContent` parameter is not `null`, the `Scaffold` just uses a `ModalDrawer` with `drawerState = scaffoldState.drawerState`.

Something like:

```
val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
Scaffold(
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    drawerContent = {
        //Your code and use drawerState = scaffoldState.drawerState.
        //Drawer( )
    },
    floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.End,
    floatingActionButton = {
        ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
            text = { Text("...") },
            onClick = { /* fab click handler */ }
        )
    },
    content = { innerPadding ->
        //Your code and and use drawerState = scaffoldState.drawerState.
        NavHost(
            navController,
            startDestination = "Screen1"
        ) {
           //....
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks. But if i use Scaffold, not able to add NavHost calls.. I want to use Navigation Component for navigation. How to add NavHost in above Scaffold code?

Comment: @chait In the content of the Scaffold. Check also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67133781/android-jetpack-compose-fragment-without-xml/67142600#67142600